# How to store the <value : number> inside the condition such that it manipulates accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function for generating the random number between 1 to 6. I am storing this number into the 'count' object. On an onClick function, the button calls the method to generate the random number.

As I am storing the current value of random number (say 2) into the 'count' object. Then I click the button to generate a new number (say 5), how could I store the 5+2 into some object such that every-time I click the random number, they get added up to the previously generated random number and get stored to the object, let's say 'updatedCount' object, so that I could use it accordingly?

```
let max = 6, min = 1;
const count = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //say i get 5
const previousCount = count; //i think it should store 5
const updatedCount = count(/*new one, say 4*/) + previousCount(/* 5*/);
console.log(updatedCount); //it should give me 9.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few things going on here:

1. generating the random number between 1 to 6
2. every-time I click the random number, they gets added up to the previously generated random number

So you have a function that:

- Creates a random number
- Adds the previous and the current random number together.

And you have some state that

- Stores the current random number.
- Stores the previous random number

So a program might look like this:

1. Handle a "click event of some some kind.
2. Move the value of the current random number, into the state for the previous random number (discard possible value for previous random number).
3. Call the function to generate a random number.
4. Store the value into the current random number.
5. Render the sum of the 2 states (previous random number and current random number)

Comment: Yes, you have a good hold of my situation. How could I do it programetically using react?

Comment: The click event, handling can be implemented using onClick JSX attribute calling a function/method. That function can use react useState (hooks) or setState (classes) alter the states. The random number can also be returned via a function/method. The returned value (hooks) or the render method (classes) can render the sum of the two states. To get started, try the getting started guide from the React website.